# java regex is returning false even if the mail id string is present in the filecontent string

Tags: java

```
          String regex = "/[a-z0-9._'-]*@[a-z]{2,6}.[a-z]{2,6}/g";
          Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
          Matcher m=pattern.matcher(filecontent);
          System.out.println(m.find());//false
```

file content string:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit   ?
>   :9705075626                                  ?  :
>   sainathreddybobbala@gmail.com
>
> ——————————————————————————————————————
>
> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
>   accusantium doloremque laudantium
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
>   mailto:sainathreddybobbala@gmail.com
>
> qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet

Comment: don't think you want the `*` at the start of regex, as it will pass `@gmail.com`, `+` would be more appropriate

Comment: Can't you at least try on a single email address before trying on your entire CV ?

Comment: btw your regex won't work for .co.uk and etc :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the forward slashes / and the g -- that's a vim & javascript reference (inter alia)

Test it at https://regex101.com/r/SR8ksW/1/